# What is the actual physical movement of the electron from the copper atom that produces electric current?

Tags: electricity, electrons, electric-current

What is the actual physical movement of the electron from the copper atom that produces electric current? Is the electron given a higher energy level and this releases the electron from the copper atom?

Answer (score 1):

No. There are already free electrons in copper. This means that they aren’t localised to any particular atom. But they are all moving randomly. So on average, there is no net direction of motion.

However, in the presence of an external field (voltage), the electrons have a net momentum against the field. Thus there is current.

Comment: In one simple model, the free electrons in a conductor bounce off of the atoms and share their thermal energy.  In the time between collisions an electric field accelerates the electrons down the wire.  The motion is still mostly random, but each jump is now curved.